# Widget Building: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is it that this works: http://jsfiddle.net/w82W8/1/
But this doesn't?: http://jsfiddle.net/w82W8/2/

This question may seem convoluted; you may wonder, why not just use the first!? Why are you using jQuery to load in JS+CSS assets that you could easily load in the original HTML.

Well, I'm in the process of building a web widget and I'd like to keep the embed code as small as possible. The idea is to have the user include a single `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mysite.com/widget.js'></script>` line in their code, and the widget.js code will take care of all the details. Including fetching fancybox.

I'm getting the error: **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'**

I hypothesize that javascript is not waiting for fancybox.js to load, and immediately attempting to apply fancybox() to the trigger. Can I get a callback working here when the assets have been loaded? I'm certain they are getting included in the DOM though... I've inspected with Chrome Tools.

I know this question has been asked on StackOverflow before, but not in this context.

Thanks, and Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the second method, the fancybox method is called before the Fancybox plugin has loaded. Use the [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method if you want to execute code *after* loading a script.

Example:

```
$.getScript(
    "http://jordanarsenault.com/fancy/fancybox.js",
    function(){
       $(".trigger").fancybox();
    }
);
```

If you need an advanced resource loader, consider using a real loader, such as [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com).

Answer (score 0):

Because the script isn't immediately loaded. You have to use `$.getScript` and supply a callback like this: http://jsfiddle.net/w82W8/3/.

```
$.getScript("http://jordanarsenault.com/fancy/fancybox.js", function() {
    $(".trigger").fancybox(); // only run when script is loaded
});
```